# GeForce/ION Driver v270.61 (XP) two different sizes mentioned on Nvidia's site

Tags: drivers, nvidia-geforce

```
GeForce/ION Driver v270.61
Version: 270.61 WHQL
Release Date: 2011.04.18
Operating System: Windows XP
Language: English (U.S.)
File Size: 84.6 MB
```

---

```
GeForce/ION Driver v270.61
Version:    270.61 WHQL
Release Date:   2011.04.18
Operating System: Windows XP
Language:   English (UK)
File Size:  118 MB
```

---

What makes the difference in driver sizes (US vs. UK versions)?

Answer (score 1):

The difference with the UK one is a few changes in terms and spelling. I don't know why it's such a large size increase, but I would just get the US version since it's still understandable.

Comment: "still understandable" :D

Comment: Language: English (India)
File Size: 84.6 MB

Comment: @slhck haha yeah it is, The only differences between US and UK english is words like color (colour) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you had this info from, but when I go to NVIDIA, select ION drivers and list the options for version 270.61, released on 2011.04.18, I can see:

```
Language: English (U.S.)
File Size: 102 MB

Language: English (UK)
File Size: 132 MB

Language: Deutsch
File Size: 132 MB

Language: Francais
File Size: 132 MB

Lingua: Italiano
Dimensioni: 132 MB
```

See a pattern?

Comment: Those are sizes of Vista / win7, mine sizes of XP drivers.

Comment: Oh well. It seems as if they just bundle several internationalized versions together.